# How to change QTP report to junit Report Format

Tags: qtp

http://www.java2s.com/Code/XML/XSLT-stylesheet/Createnewelementwithattribute.htm

This is my XSLT

iexplore
                
                    
                
                
                    
                
                
                    
                
                
                    
                
                
                    
                
                QTP

This is my QTP Report XML

simclass = DV2ControlHost
regexpwndtitle = Start Menu
regexpwndclass = DV2ControlHost
is owned window = -1
is child window = 0
]]>



















Line (1): "Window("Window").Window("Start Menu").WinButton("All Programs").Click". ]]>

I want to change This Format